# Effective method getting the topmost path element in perl

Tags: perl

Have

```
my $path = "//strange/path/";
```

need get the 1st element with (one) leading slash = `/strange` or only the `/` is the $path is empty or contains only slashes.

Currently have two solutions, e.g.:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use File::Spec;
my $path = "//strange/path/";

#version with File::Spec
my $v1 = "/" . ([grep {/./} File::Spec->splitdir($path)]->[0] //  "");
say $v1;

#regex
my $v2 = $path;
$v2 =~ s{^/*}{};
$v2 =~ s{/.*}{};
$v2 =~ s{^}{/};
say $v2;
```

I don't like any of them, because the 1.st uses module, and 3 regexes in the second is simply ugly.

Exists more effective || fastest || "nicer" method?

Comment: Personally I like ways that use modules, especially if it's a standard module like `File::Spec`. You can be reasonable sure that the code has been tested and proved valid by thousands of users (unlike your own self-cooked regexes), and `File::Spec` provides automatic cross-platform functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want regex, you can try the following "one regex" solution:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $o = my $n = $_;
    $n =~ s:(^/*)([^/]*)?(/*.*):/$2:;
    say "=$o= =$n=";
}
__DATA__

/
//
strange
strange/
strange/path
/strange
/strange/
/strange/path
//strange
//strange/
//strange/path
//strange//
//strange//
//strange//path
```

but as above @Moritz Bunkus told - the best is use the standard File::Spec.

Comment: ok, will use the File::Spec. ;) Accepting this as only answer.